# Check if two or more tasks have failed

Tags: airflow

I am trying to build such logic:

```
task_1 >> state
task_2 >> state
task_3 >> state
```

In the "state" I need to check, that if two out of three tasks have failed, then DAG should fail. Also, state should be executed only when all "tasks_x" are completed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TaskInstance](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html) to get list of failed tasks. Here is an example:

```
def state(ti: TaskInstance, **kwargs):
    # find failed tasks
    failed = ti.get_dagrun().get_task_instances(state=TaskInstanceState.FAILED)

    if len(failed) >= 2:
        raise Exception('State failed')
    # processing...
```